# "I'm thinking of" vs "I'm wondering" vs "I wonder"

Tags: expressions

When we want to say that we have been thinking (for days) before taking a decision, I'm use to saying

```
I'm thinking of hiring another employee...
```

Are there any other ways of saying the same thing?

```
I wonder hiring another employee...
```

By the way, is that right saying `I'm wondering`?

Comment: I wondered lonely as a cloud ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I am thinking of hiring another employee" is the right expression. It suggests that one is reasonably aware of the need to hire. There are 30900 results when I google the full sentence.

"I wonder hiring another employee" sounds incomplete. 
The sentence - "I wonder if hiring another employee is worth it" - will be a coherent message, i.e. you are unsure of it. 
One of the meanings of 'wonder' according to dictionary.com is "to feel doubt"